# NODE.JS Multidimensional/Sub array PUSH prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, array-push

I am attempting to sort data into an appropriate category of array once parsed;

First lets initialize my Array like so.

```
const foo = {
    bar: {},
    bar2: {}
}
```

I am unable to utilize the .push prototype on the subarray build, for example.

```
foo.bar.push('foobar');
```

The error I will receive is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

The array has been initialized using the first block of code.

I have also attempted to use the following and receive the same response from the console.

```
foo[0].push('foobar');
```

How could one push data to a subarray?

**BONUS POINTS/PS.**
What is this kind of array called? Is this a subarray or multidimensional array or neither?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `What is this kind of array called?` which kind? `{}` is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: `{}` = `new Object()` and `[]` = `new Array()`

Comment: @RenéDatenschutz no it's not, it's without the constructor call.

Comment: @AZ_ it's with the constructor, without is sugar https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are declaring is an object not array.

```
const foo = {
    bar: {},
    bar2: {}
}
```

In this case bar and bar2 both are objects and not array. And push is not available on object's prototype.

Use this to declare arrays inside object.

```
const foo = {
    bar: [],
    bar2: []
}
```

Comment: You saved the day! and bonus points as well! This is an OBJECT not array

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to shubham-gupta response that if you want to push to `foo` you should declare it as an array as well:

```
const foo = [{
    bar: [],
    bar2: []
}]
```

Comment: then you can't do `foo.bar.push('foobar');`

Comment: Correct, you should use `foo[0].bar.push('poteto')`

Answer (score 0):

Christopher, the error says what it says because, it is not possible to **push** an element into an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), but only an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Check [this page](https://dev.to/zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-2g0e) out, which differentiate the two.

To set the value of a key inside an object you do:
`<your_object>.<your_key>= <your_value>`;

To push an element into an array, you do: `<your_array>.push(<your_element>);`

Hence the `bar` elements inside `foo` should be arrays => [], not objects;

In your case here, you seem to be wanting to push the element **"foobar"** into the array `bar` inside of the object `foo`.

To do that, all you need to do is:

```
const foo = {
    bar: [],
    bar2: []
}
foo.bar.push('foobar');
```